# View HDMI output from another device on a Mid-2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, video, hdmi

I'm looking for a setup that will allow me to view the video output from another device (1080p/60 over HDMI) on my MacBook, at full frame rate and with minimal latency. I assume this would take the form of a Thunderbolt dongle, but I don't know what to look for, or if such a thing even exists.

I don't need to be able to capture or encode video, though being able to save frames would be a plus. I'd also like to be able to view the video output scaled to full-screen, and if there's the option of software filtering (e.g. sharpening / fancy upscaling), that would be a plus as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question would be a better fit for a site like [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) because it's not about Apple products per se

Comment: Also....  two things to keep in mind - you will need to capture HDMI out to view it elsewhere and no matter the hardware, there's going to be a lag.  You're not splitting an HDMI signal nor is a computer an HDMI display device.  Converting from output to input (to be processed by your CPU/GPU) back to output (for display on your screen) **will** cause lag.

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure. While it would certainly fit on hardwarecs, isn't it also a valid question here? It's asking what hardware compliments Apple hardware; there's certainly a precedent for that already.

Comment: @JMY1000 What makes the "device" in question specific to Apple?  Or, put it another way, what in this scenario, using a MacBook Pro as the viewing device, make it unique?

Comment: @Allan Capture cards output over a specific IO channel (read: MacBook has USB/Thunderbolt), and usually cards require specific software. Depending on implementation/support, a given card could be better/worse suited for macOS.

Comment: They *capture* over specific IO channels, they transmit over standard USB.  USB AV devices, if they adhere to standards are typically driverless. Additionally, *driver availability* isn't unique attribute  In hardwarerecs, *platform* is a criteria you *must* specify.

Comment: @Allan Noone said that there wouldn’t be lag. Of course there will! I wrote low-latency in my answer. Basically if you’re a pro-gamer, you are going to be able to measure and feel latency. If you’re a casual gamer or typical home user - it will not be a problem. People are using the HD60 S to display their gaming console output on their computer display, and are able to play their games without problems.

Comment: @allan A device such as the HD60 S is not driverless. It will not work without without specific macOS drivers. In fact, this product was on the market for a while supporting only Windows - and only later macOS support was released in the form of drivers. Linux support is still sketchy.

Comment: @Allan They can transmit over other things (add-in PCI-e cards, Thunderbolt, Firewire, etc.) Even over USB, they aren't always driverless: see Blackmagic's devices. in any case, platform is important here. Not sure if it still belongs necessarily (might just be poorly suited to this site in the same way Xcode related issues usually get moved to stackoverflow), but eh.

Comment: As far as I can see this is a fully valid question here - similar to asking which type of display cable is compatible with a specific Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a device such as the Elgato HD60 S, which offers low-latency capture from a 1080p60 HDMI source, which you can view on your MacBook over a USB 3.0 connection.

It also allows you to save and stream the video if you want to do that as well.

It's available from for example Amazon at $179.95:

[https://www.amazon.com/Elgato-Game-Capture-HD60-technology/dp/B01DRWCOGA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DRWCOGA)

Comment: The HD60 lagged badly for me (something like 400ms), but I think the HD60s should be faster.

Comment: Yes, the S is much, much faster. The HD60 is a USB 2.0 device which is a real limitation. Lag in the hundreds of ms is to be expected there. The HD60 S is one or two orders of magnitude better when it comes to latency.